# Determine all c such that $a_0=0 ; a_{n+1}=\frac{a_n^2+c}{2}$ converges

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Dertemine all c such that the recursive sequence ${a_n}$ defined by setting

$a_0=0 ; a_{n+1}=\dfrac{a_n^2+c}{2}$ converges.

I can prove that if $-3\le c\le 1$  then $a_n $converge. But I can't find all c.

Comment: Any thoughts on the problem yourself?

Comment: Can you please provide your working for $-3\leq c\leq1$ case?

Comment: Let $b_n=\dfrac{a_n}{2}$ and you'll get the standard quadratic iteration $b_{n+1}=b_n^2+\dfrac{c}{4}$.